# Response.Write against @variable when outputting json

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-webpages

ASP.NET Web Pages 2 sample api.cshtml file:

This code return proper json that is recognized by a jquery $.ajax call:

```
@{
    var data1 = AppFunctions.PerformSelect(AppState["U1select"].ToString());
    var jsondata = Json.Encode(data1);
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Response.Write(jsondata);
}
```

but this doesn't. why?

```
@{
    var data1 = AppFunctions.PerformSelect(AppState["U1select"].ToString());
    var jsondata = Json.Encode(data1);
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
}
@jsondata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to Razor rather than a json output issue - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611858/74309).

Instead of `Response.Write(jsondata)` have you used `Html.Raw(jsondata)` or `Html.Output(jsondata)`?